# python: KeyError when remove a set from a given list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, collections, set

I am using Python-3.4 through Jupyter Notebook. I use the following code to remove a dirty set from a given list:

```
clean_set = set(given_list).remove(dirty_set)
```

But got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-8c7b49a49cb5> in <module>()
----> 1 clean_set = set(given_list).remove(dirty_set)

KeyError: {'730', 'C07', '5Q2', ...}
```

Any idea what I missed? Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to find `set(given_list) - dirty_set` ?

Comment: Considering  a set cannot contains sets, I doubt your list contains sets, else you shouldn't have a `KeyError` but a `TypeError`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh: Yes

Comment: @ Moses Koledoye: I am trying to remove the elements in dirty_set from the given_list. Could you please elaborate more about "a set cannot contains sets" ? Thanks!

Comment: @Edamame The snippet I gave does that.  [See Here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)  Sets can only contain hashable items.  Sets themselves are not hashable (because they are mutable, meaning they can change)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh: I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the dirty items from your list using a list comprehension:

```
clean_list = [i for i in given_list if i not in dirty_set]
```

Or using the difference of sets if you want duplicates removed:

```
clean_set = set(given_list).difference(dirty_set)
```

You can use the `-` operator if `dirty_set` is already a set but `set.difference` is more preferable since it takes any iterable.